# Unable to send data (1) from MATLAB to Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, arduino-uno

I am sending `1` from MATLAB to Arduino. My Arduino code works perfectly when I send `1` from teraterm terminal software. But when I send `1` from MATLAB by using this code arduino TX lite blinks but cannot get the `1` output.

```
s = serial('COM7','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(s)
fprintf(s,'1');
fclose(s)
```

Comment: try specifying a format for (fprintf)[http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fprintf.html] to suppress the `\n` at the end of the string if that is not expected. if it will always be a single char, format using `%c`.

Comment: Any update for this question? Have you checked the parity and other parameters for the serial usage?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with this code is that you are not giving Delay to process the code.

According to my calculation : fopen(string) command needs 0.8754 Seconds of Processing time.

So add 1 second delay, it will work.
..
Your Modified Code :

```
clear all
clc
s=serial('COM7','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(s);
pause(1);
fprintf(s,1);
fclose(s);
```